# How to pass session value in webdriver switchTo().window method

Tags: webdriver

I need to pass session value from one window other window.  I am sing switchto() method in WebDriver, if I need to do new window's  findElement(By.LinkText). click() event, as session value is not sending link is becoming invalid.

Please provide any example which handles passing session values.

Thanks in advance.

Venkat

Comment: Ok First get the window elements with 

 

    `String window = driver.getWindowHandle();`

Then switch to the window you want to work on using

 `driver.switchTo().window("Name of the window you want to switch");`

    Perform your operation in this window (new window) using `driver.findele.....`

Once you are done switch back to default window using

 `driver.switchTo().window(window);`

Answer (score 0):

This script helps you to switch over from a Parent window to a Child window and back cntrl to Parent window

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String windowHandle  : handles)
{
   if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
   {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        //Perform your operation here for new window
        driver.close(); //closing child window
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); //cntrl to parent window
    }
}
```